# apex repeat to show data in two columns

Tags: visualforce

I am using a apex repeat which is giving me details as below

data1

data2

data3

data4

I want to display it as

```
<table>
<tr><td>data1</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;data2</td></tr><br/>
<tr><td>data3</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;data4</td></tr>
</html>
```

and so on..

Can any help me on this???

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to achieve. Try something like this.

```
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:repeat value="{!myWrapperList}" var="obj">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        {!obj.a.id}
        {!obj.a.name}
        {!obj.a.BillingCity}
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The default number of columns for PageBlockSection is 2. If you want to change that add the columns attribute in pageBlockSection

Comment: [apex:panelGrid](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm) is designed for this situation in mind. It will dynamically make a table of the specified columns using the elements within.

Answer (score 0):

Use pageBlock with columns as 2, and do repeat..
it works :)

Comment: apex:pageBlockSection ... sorry

Comment: Not a realy correct answer. He wants to have two different records in one column.